# Wicket custom (data)table layout

Tags: datatable, wicket

Is there a way to customize the wicket `DataTable` layout?
I'd like to have a `DataTable` with a horizontal flow of data and multiple columns per row.

e.g.:

```
------------------------------
|prename| John| surname| Doe |
------------------------------
|city   | NY  | country| USA |
------------------------------
```

Unlike the normal use of the `DataTable` class this would be used for displaying just one object (respectively one dataset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `DataTable` for this.

For a simple case, just make a panel containing a `Label` for each data element and put the table layout in the corresponding html fragment.

To make it more dynamic, with parametrized size as noted in your comment, you might build your own structure using nested `RepeatingView` components, one for the rows and one for the columns, or perhaps use a `DataGridView`, which would do some of the layout work for you.

But `DataTable` is really meant for a table with meaningful columnar structure and includes alot of code for handling the column structure which won't make sense for your data and will get in your way.

Comment: Thanks Don for your answer. The thing is, I want to make the whole table dynamic with variable length of input data (and maybe even a parameter to define the column length).

Comment: Thanks again. I tried subclassing `DataViewBase` but the problem is that I don't have access to the column names, just for the data itself.

Comment: Solved it with 2 RepeatingViews and some Panels, thanks for the hints!